# How to use HTTP PATCH for a request where the body is XML?

Tags: http, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I have seen examples of the request body of an HTTP PATCH request that contains JSON.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902

An implementation of that (from https://www.mnot.net/blog/2012/09/05/patch) could look like:

```
[
  {"replace": "/count", "value": 5}
]
```

I haven't seen examples of that with XML, though. Does anyone know if people are using XML as the request data format for PATCH requests?

Thanks!

Comment: People are using it, but there's no standard yet. XML is tricky to patch correctly when you have to provide a generic standard. A quick google search should turn up some options, or you can provide a custom implementation.

Comment: The linked article links to a standard: [RFC5261 - An Extensible Markup Language (XML) Patch Operations Framework Utilizing XML Path Language (XPath) Selectors](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5261).

Comment: Thanks Eric and lefloh. That standard does seem to exist, but I wasn't sure if people are actually using it. There's been some adoption around json-patch and HTTP Patch in general (Rails 4, in particular) from what I've read. It seems that most people are sticking with POST/PUT, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard, you just need the XML to describe the updates you want to make. It could be something absolute or relative.

```
<userUpdates>
  <itemsViewed relative=true>3</itemsViewed>
  <lastViewed>your mum</lastViewed>
</userUpdates>
```

Here I assumed that by default you set values absolutely.